# How to assign values in an array of arrays properly?

Tags: arrays, c, pointer-arithmetic

Is there a way to assign values in an array of arrays?

Specifically, I have written the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int **A){  //A: address of (address that the pointer stores)
  int i;
  *A=(int *)malloc(5*sizeof(int));    //*A: address that the pointer stores
  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    **A=i;          //**A: content
  }
}

int main(){
  int *k, i;
  func(&k);

  for (i=0;i<5;i++){
    printf("%d ", k[i]); 
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The statement `**A=i` inside the function, seems to assign the values only in the first place of the array (the output is `4 0 0 0 0` each time I execute the code).

I have also tried using `*A[i]=i`  instead. In this case, the compiler terminates the execution with the following message: `signal: illegal instruction (core dumped)` .

Is there anything I could do to solve this?

Comment: **Returning** the array with something like `int *func(void)...` and then `int *k = func();` would be much easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several equivalent constructions that allow to do that.

Here you are

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  A[0][i] = i; 
}
```

or

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  ( *A )[i] = i;
}
```

or

```
for (i=0;i<5;i++){
  *( *A + i ) = i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The array index operator `[]` has higher precedence than the dereference operator `*`.

You'll need to use parenthesis do what you want.

```
(*A)[i]=i;
```